# True or false, if function f : X → Y is onto, then $Codomain(f)\nsubseteq range(f)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If function f : X → Y is onto, then is $Codomain(f)\nsubseteq range(f)$ ?  I believe the answer is false, because the range is a set within the co-domain, so if anything, $range(f)\nsubseteq Codomain(f)$

Can anybody tell me if I am correct in this?

Comment: What is $f$?  Presumably it's not the same thing as $F$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to have all of the f's in lower case.  They are the same.

Comment: By range do you mean image? I thought range and codomain refer to the same set, namely some superset of the image.

Comment: @user4894: Another fairly standard usage of *range* is identical to image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we say that $f:X\to Y$ is onto (or that $f$ is a function from $X$ onto $Y$) if and only if the range of $f$ is $Y$.

Now, anytime we write $f:X\to Y,$ we indicate that $f$ is a function from $X$ *into* $Y,$ that last part meaning that the range of $f$ is a subset of $Y.$ Hence $f:X\to Y$ is onto if and only if $Y$ is a subset of the range of $f$.

*Nota bene*: It doesn't really make sense to talk about **the** codomain of a function $f$, because a codomain is simply any set containing the range of $f$. We can certainly specify ***a*** codomain of $f$ by using the notation $f:X\to Y.$ This is just shorthand to say that (1) $f$ is a function, (2) $X$ is the domain of $f,$ and (3) $Y$ is a codomain of $f$ (that we happen to be considering for some reason).

Comment: thank you for  this info.  I am not 100% I understand yet.  Does this mean that it is safe to say that the codomain(f) is a subset of range(f) and vise versa?

Comment: The range of $f$ will always be a subset of any codomain of $f$. The reverse holds *exactly when* $f$ is onto.

Comment: Gotcha, makes perfect sense.  Thank you!